# How to do method aliasing in groovy?

Tags: groovy, methods, alias

I am trying to redefine dynamic methods of a domain in groovy. Is there something similar alias method in ruby in groovy?

Answer (score 31):

Do you mean like the method reference operator `.&` ?

```
def out = System.out.&println
out << "Hello"
```

and

```
def greet(name) {
    println "Hello $name"
}

def sayHello = this.&greet

sayHello "Ronny"
```

It is mentioned at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators but an example is missing

Comment: This seems to have issues when subclassing and using generics.  I have `Pair<T>` and `Foo<T> extends Pair<T>`.  I have `T first` defined as a property on `Pair`. On `Foo`, define `public getBar = this.&getFirst`.  If I try to use as, `Foo<Integer> f = new Foo<>(1,10)`, then `f.getBar()` returns `Closure<Object>`.   Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using [metaprogramming](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass):

```
MyClass.metaClass.aliasMethod = MyClass.metaClass.originalMethod
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [method pointer operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#method-pointer-operator) (`.&`), there's the **equivalent [method reference operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73337405/15016163) (`::`)** for *Groovy version 3.0.0 and above* which is more compatible with Java. **Read my answer on [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73337405/15016163)**.

```
def foo(bar) {
    println "foo $bar"
}

def bar = this.&foo
bar "foo"

def out = System.out::println
out << "Hello"
```

Output

```
foo foo
Hello
```