# Pass method as parameter in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming, closures

Is there a way to pass a method as a parameter in Groovy without wrapping it in a closure? It seems to work with functions, but not methods. For instance, given the following:

```
def foo(Closure c) {
    c(arg1: "baz", arg2:"qux")
}

def bar(Map args) {
    println('arg1: ' + args['arg1'])
    println('arg2: ' + args['arg2'])
}
```

This works:

```
foo(bar)
```

But if `bar` is a method in a class:

```
class Quux { 
    def foo(Closure c) {
        c(arg1: "baz", arg2:"qux")
    }

    def bar(Map args) {
        println('arg1: ' + args['arg1'])
        println('arg2: ' + args['arg2'])
    }

    def quuux() { 
      foo(bar)
    }
} 

new Quux().quuux()
```

It fails with **No such property: bar for class: Quux**.

If I change the method to wrap `bar` in a closure, it works, but seems unnecessarily verbose:

```
    def quuux() { 
      foo({ args -> bar(args) })
    }
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the [method pointer operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#method-pointer-operator) (`.&`), for *Groovy version 3.0.0 and above* there's the equivalent, compatible, well known Java 8+ [method reference operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#method-reference-operator) (`::`).

```
def foo(Closure c) {
    c(func: "foo")
}

def bar(Map args = [:]) {
    println "$args.func bar"
}

println foo(this::bar)
```

Output:

```
foo bar
```

The method reference operator, as stated in [Groovy's documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#method-reference-operator):

> […] overlaps somewhat with the functionality provided by Groovy’s
> method pointer operator. Indeed, for dynamic Groovy, the method
> reference operator is just an alias for the method pointer operator.
> For static Groovy, the operator results in bytecode similar to the
> bytecode that Java would produce for the same context.

Answer (score 76):

`.&` operator to the rescue!

```
class Quux { 
    def foo(Closure c) {
        c(arg1: "baz", arg2:"qux")
    }

    def bar(Map args) {
        println('arg1: ' + args['arg1'])
        println('arg2: ' + args['arg2'])
    }

    def quuux() { 
      foo(this.&bar)
    }
} 

new Quux().quuux()
// arg1: baz
// arg2: qux
```

In general, `obj.&method` will return a bound method, i.e. a closure that calls `method` on `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a unit test with Groovy 2.3.7:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase

class ClosureTest extends TestCase {

    String foo(Closure c) {
        return c(func: "foo")
    }

    String bar(Map args = [:]) {
        return "$args.func bar"
    }

    void testFunctionCall() {
        assertEquals("foo bar", foo(this.&bar))
    }

}
```