# Code works in shell but not as a script - MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy, higher-order-functions

I'm learning Groovy and came across this curious behavior. Executing the following code in `groovysh` works without a problem, but saving it as 'foo.groovy' and running it via `groovy foo.groovy` results in a `MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: foo` in line 3:

```
def a(n) { n*n }
def x(m) { m(2) }
x(a)
```

Changing `a` to a closure `a = { n -> n*n }` makes this error go away, but I'd like to avoid that for my real use case which is more complex. I've also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231810/pass-method-as-parameter-in-groovy) which deals with the same problem *inside of a class*, but the solution using `this.&` isn't applicable as my method isn't inside of a class, and coming from a python background I'd like to keep it that way.

What am I doing wrong? And where is this behavior documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `groovysh` stores:

```
def a(n) { n*n }
```

as a MethodClosure into a binding variable called `a`

This will not happen outside of groovysh, and as you have seen you'll need to define a as a closure:

```
def a = { n -> n*n }
def x( m ) { m( 2 ) }
x(a)
```

Or use the method reference operator `&`:

```
def a(n) { n*n }
def x(m) { m(2) }
x( this.&a )
```